# Basic Symfony 2 Object-Entity understanding

Tags: symfony

I have two entities, `event` and `participant`. They have a relation, like every event can have many participants.

`participants` have properties like checked, visible and so on.

normaly i can do some like `$event->getParticipant();` in my controller.

what is now the best way to get more specific selections? for example i want to do implement some of the following functions:

```
$event->getVisibleParticipant();
$event->getCheckedParticipant();
$event->getVisibleAndCheckedParticipant();
```

how and where can i implement such functions the best way?

I have tried to implement a EventRepository, but it says that the method i want to call there is undefined...

Comment: Can you show your entity class and entity repository ?

Comment: its similar to what peter bailey has postet

Comment: ok have you this annotation for use your repository : 
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Bundle\YourBundle\Entity\EntityRepository")

Comment: i did it i thought that was the problem but it still didnt work :/

Comment: it says FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Proxies\__CG__\...\..Bundle\Entity\Event::getVisibleParticipants() in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\..\..\src\...\..Bundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 47

Comment: ok, the problem is, that u cannot access repository functions from within an object of an entity.

Comment: Yes u must use the entity manager and get your function like this : $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$entities = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:YourEntity')->getVisibleParticipant();

Answer (score 1):

You can probably best accomplish this with Doctrine's `filter` method for collections

http://api.nellafw.org/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html

So, on your `Event` entity, let's assume your relationship looks like this

```
<?php

namespace /Your/Bundle/Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Event
{
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Participant", mappedBy="event")
   */
  protected $participants;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->participants = new ArrayCollection();
  }
}
```

So all you need to do is add a query method (to the `Event` entity) that will use the filtering capabilities of Doctrine's collections

```
/**
 * Retrieves all associated participants that are visible
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
public function getVisibleParticipants()
{
  return $this->participants->filter( function( Participant $participant )
  {
    // Add only visible participants to the returned collection
    return (boolean) $participant->getVisible();
  });
}
```

Comment: no i dont understand that. so best way is to put a method in the entity.
but what with getVisibleAndChecked? where do i know that getVisible() method exists?

Comment: is it possible (and wise?) to do some custom db-queries in the entity?

Comment: and: i have guessed this is a very common task. did everyone else do every time custom queries in the controller for things like that?

Comment: 1) I assumed that `Participant::getVisible()` existed because your question states that participant entities have a `visible` property.

2) No, you should not have query logic in your entities. If you want to make custom queries for a given Entity, those should go in the corresponding EntitiyRepository